# Why the hair particles doesn´t show up in render mode?

Tags: particles, hair

I´m trying to addd fur to this hat but it´s not working somehow.
The hair particles look like this even in render mode.
Does anyone know what could it be?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hey Samantha.  This looks like proper behavior to me, perhaps I'm missing something, though.  Can you include more pictures of what you consider to be the problem, and what you expect the result to be?

Comment: If you want more coverage you'll need more particles.  The Children menu can create multiple child particles for each of the parent particles you have now.